# Update library module's targetSdkVersion when updating app's targetSdkVersion

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, target-sdk

I have an app which uses a library module, both having targetSdkVersion 21. 
Now I want to make my app marshmallow compatible. So while updating my app's targetSdkVersion to 23, do I need to update library module also ?

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to always target the latest SDK available. If you upgrade your app's `targetSdkVersion` to 23, but leave your library's `targetSdkVersion` in 21, resources coming from the library will be styled targeting 21 even though you might be running on 23.